# OpenSuse Leap 15.2 Unable to install docker (GLIBC_2.32 required, but only 2.26 is available)

Tags: linux, docker, glibc, opensuse, zypper

I am unable to install docker on open suse 15.2, the glibc version does not satisfy docker's dependency:

```
sudo zypper install docker docker-bash-completion python3-docker-compose
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...
2 Problems:
Problem: nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.32)(64bit) needed by docker-20.10.3_ce-9.2.x86_64
Problem: nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.32) needed by docker-20.10.3_ce-9.2.i586

Problem: nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.32)(64bit) needed by docker-20.10.3_ce-9.2.x86_64
 Solution 1: do not install docker-20.10.3_ce-9.2.x86_64
 Solution 2: break docker-20.10.3_ce-9.2.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or skip, retry or cancel [1/2/s/r/c/d/?] (c):
```

I have attempted to update glibc, however:

```
No update candidate for 'glibc-2.26-lp152.26.3.1.x86_64'. The highest available version is already installed.
```

I am reluctant to install a higher version of glibc from source, as we all know how catastrophic messing with glibc can be!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way to solve this (for now at least) was to install docker via snapcraft (snap) which has got me up and running again.

See also: https://snapcraft.io/install/docker/opensuse

As I understand it, snap packages contain all there dependencies and do not rely on system shared objects.